# How to suspend and resume function of C++11 std::thread without touching the function itself?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, std

I can wrap the desired function within another and manage e.g. that it would start when a condition fulfilled, but an 'endless loop' should not be organized around it. As far as I know `pthread` supports suspend/resume by condition variables combined with muteces: wait/signal.

Comment: As you say, your thread function *can* use mutexes and other synchronisation objects to be effectively paused in a cooperative manner, but there is no way from the stdlib interface to externally influence the scheduling of a thread. Nothing in the pthread API either. What was your question again?

Comment: Are you looking for a threadpool? If so try this one https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool

Answer (score 1):

`std::thread` will just run it's Callable argument to completion, and the only interaction available is to `join` or `detatch`. The closest that you can get to what you want is to interrogate the `native_handle` and do platform dependant things to that.